# Better way to only include real filesystems in find?

Tags: bash, find

This works, and is generic across systems (at least Ubuntu 18.04 and RHEL 8.3) with different mountpoints, but is there a Better Way?

(Ignore that I'm trying to find `pg_ctl` and excluding "Permission denied".  `find` is what I'm asking about.)

```
$ realfs=$(df -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $6;}' | xargs)
$ echo $realfs
/ /boot/efi /Database/12 /Database/12/backups
$ find ${realfs} -xdev -type f -name pg_ctl |& grep -v "Permission denied"  
/usr/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/lib64/pgsql/postgresql-10/bin/pg_ctl
```

I developed this method not only because the method needs to be generic across systems with different mountpoints, but also because `-prune` is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, the supported file systems are listed in `/proc/filesystems`; those which *aren’t* physical, local file systems are marked with `nodev`. Thus

```
fs=($(grep -v '^nodev' /proc/filesystems))
```

gives an array of the types you’re interested in, which can then be used with `find`’s `-fstype`:

```
findfs=($(echo ${fs[*]/#/ -o -fstype }))
find / \( -false ${findfs[*]} \)
```

This avoids hard-coding a set of file systems to *exclude* ahead of time. It does have some drawbacks, notably it excludes networked file systems which may be a problem in some scenarios.

Comment: That's more robust, given that I only excluded two common nodev FSs.